# Conversion failed in SQL procedure while executing from C#

Tags: c#, sql, openrowset

I have a SQL stored procedure which uses openrowset command and fetches values from an excel sheet and inserts it into the database.

I have created a C# application which will call the procedure and execute it.

**PROBLEM!**

When I execute the procedure from SQL management studio, there are no errors. It happens perfectly. But when I execute it through the C# application I get an error: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

**Code**

**SQL Query** (only the insert part)

```
insert into  tbl_item ([Item code],[Dt Created])

select[Item code] ,

case when [Dt Created] is null or [Dt Created]='' then null when ISDATE(CONVERT(nvarchar,CONVERT(datetime, [Dt Created],103))) =1 then CONVERT(datetime, [Dt Created],103) else null end as [Dt Created]    

FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Upload\Report.xlsx;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;',
                    'select * from [Sheet1$]')
```

**C# Code**

```
public int updateItem()
{
        SqlCommand cmd; cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_updateItem", conn); 
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
        returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        try
        {
            if (conn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
                conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ret = Convert.ToInt32(returnParameter.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            err = "Error: " + e.Message;
            return -1;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: I think you forgot to paste your CODE :D :P

Comment: The C# code is just a simple ExecuteNonQuery ... Just a call to the SQL procedure.. So didn't bother posting it :)

Answer (score 2):

What is the format you are having in the [Dt Created] variable.

the convert statement you have in the case will convert only the following types below

> YYYY-MM-DD
>
> YYYY-DD-MM
>
> DD-MM-YYYY

The error you are getting is since you have a date in the format of "MM-DD-YYYY" something like '12-24-2015'. Due to this you are getting the conversion error.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me I want to stop you here. Your problem has resolved now but whatever 
***Karthik Venkatraman*** had said is correct. Somehow you got solution but for learning purpose i recommended to investigate little bit more. This is not belongs to the whatever you have said but damm sure this belongs to date-format.

**

**One trick**

Create one DateTimeVariable and once its initialized then just parse it using DateTimeParse class according to the records exist in database.

I am sure you will get solution.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally solved it...

The SQL error message 'Failed Conversion' was absolutely a wrong pointer. It had no connection to the issue at hand.  [If only I knew this before :( ]

The actual problem was that I had called another procedure within the main procedure I had posted above. This setup ran perfectly in SQL management studio which was running under my credentials. Now in the C# application, I had created another SQL login user ID to run it. And this user ID did not have execute permission to run the sub procedure. And ironically, SQL gave me a misleading conversion error. Once I gave the right permission it worked perfectly.